# c - print file in hexa after fread

Tags: c

I have this code that read binary file content and then write it but `fwrite` print it as chars and I need to print the hexa value of each byte. I only find a way to do it using `fprint` (using format '%x')

```
void PrintHex(int *buffer, int length){
    fwrite(buffer,length, 1 ,stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *inptr = fopen ( argv[1], "rb");

    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could notopen %s", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    int buffer[1000];

    while (fread (&buffer, 1, 1, inptr) == 1)
    {
          PrintHex(buffer, 1);
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `printf("%x", ...)`?

Comment: Don't use `&` on arrays. They already decay to a pointer. Use `fread(buffer, ...` instead

Comment: @MOehm the function `hexaPrint` get length and need to print <length> of bytes

Comment: Do you know how to print 1 byte in hex using `printf`? Put that in a loop to write `length` bytes. And you can also use a local buffer and `sprintf` to prepare a complete string before writing the whole thing.

Comment: Of course, `printf` alone won't do you any good. You must call it in a loop and perhaps keep track of line lengths, so that you can wrap long lines. Nice exercise. `:)`

Comment: thanks! each item in the buffer is of type int. so buffer[0] is 4 byes and I need to convert each 1 byte to hex. how can I do it?

Comment: never mind. I can use char :)

Comment: You only read 1 byte at a time anyway.